# Did anyone have worked using Autostop listener in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, listener, jmeter-plugins

Did anyone have worked using Autostop listener in jmeter ?

I have added this listener to my thread group and set the 'average response time greater than' value that its actually smaller than the output response time of executed test .

For example executed test's average response time coming around 1000 ms and I have set 'average response time greater than' to 500 ms so that execution get automatically stopped as response time is more than the set one in autostop listener . But it does not automatically stopping execution of test when average response time go higher than 500 ms.

Could anyone please explain its actual working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here I am asking that Autostop listener does not stopping the execution of threads after meeting the conditions specified in it .In jmeter.log its showing test shutdown but not in Jmeter UI. So need to know how can I use the AutoStop Listener to make it clear in an automated run that the test has failed?

Comment: I have similar issue, what's your jmeter version and plugin version?